# How can I get the simplest result of this sum?

Tags: summation

I am trying to find the sum $$\sum _{k=1}^n
   \frac{k+1}{(k-1)!+k!+(k+1)!
   }.$$
I tried

```
Simplify[Sum[(k + 1)/(( k - 1)! + k! + (k + 1)!), {k, 1, n}]]
```

and got

> (-4 - 4 n - n^2 + (1 + n) n! + (1 + n) (1 + n)! + (2 + n)! + 
>    n (2 + n)!)/((1 + n) (n! + (1 + n)! + (2 + n)!))

and tried

```
FullSimplify[Sum[(k + 1)/(( k - 1)! + k! + (k + 1)!), {k, 1, n}]]
```

> 1 - 1/Gamma[2 + n]

How can I get the result like *Maple*?

[image]

Comment: Note that with the default complexity function, definition given as `SimplifyCount` in the documentation on `ComplexityFunction`, `1 - 1/Gamma[2 + n]` has the same complexity as `1 - 1/Factorial[1 + n]` (12).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Simplify@Simplify`SimplifyGamma[Sum[(k + 1)/((k - 1)! + k! + (k + 1)!), {k, 1, n}]] 
% // TeXForm
```

> $1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

or

```
Simplify @ Developer`GammaSimplify[Sum[(k + 1)/((k - 1)! + k! + (k + 1)!), {k, 1, n}]] 
% // TeXForm
```

> $1-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$

Answer (score 1):

*Mathematica*'s result

```
1 - 1/Gamma[2 + n]
```

is equivalent to Maple's for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, but is also a correct generalization for non-integer $n$.