# Show Factorial instead of Gamma in the result of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

```
Clear["Global`*"];

f[x_] := (Cos[x]^(2 n))

int=Assuming[Element[n,PositiveIntegers], Integrate[f[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}]]

(*(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + n])/Gamma[1 + n]*)
```

I tried:

```
Developer`GammaSimplify@int

(*(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + n])/Gamma[1 + n]*)

Simplify`SimplifyGamma@int

(*(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + n])/Gamma[1 + n]*)
```

I want to get `Factorial` instead of `Gamma`. As commented by @Michael E2, it should be a double factorial, `Factorial2`:

***$\frac{2 \pi(2 n-1) ! !}{(2 n) ! !}$***

I think the key point is that I cannot expand `Gamma[1/2+n]` into `Factorial` using the *MMA* function or code.

Related:

[Show Factorial instead of Gamma in the result of RSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100409/69835)

[How can I get the simplest result of this sum?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180472/69835)

Comment: If $n$ is a positive integer, then you could use the rule `Gamma[n_ + 1/2] -> 2^-n Sqrt[\[Pi]] (-1 + 2 n)!!`.

Comment: If you merely want to get only factorials, use the rule `Gamma[z_] :> (z - 1)!`

Comment: You call it `Factorial` but you show a double factorial ($(2n)!!$ = `Factorial2[2n]`). Which do you mean?

Comment: Great. Thank you all!

Comment: @Michael E2  You're right. Thank you for telling me that there is a `Factorial2` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int = (2 Sqrt[π] Gamma[1/2 + n])/Gamma[1 + n];

Assuming[n >= 0 && Element[n, Integers],
  int /. Gamma[t_] -> 2^(1-t) (π/2)^((1-Cos[2π(t-1)])/4) (2(t-1))!! //FullSimplify]

(*    (2 π (-1 + 2 n)!!)/(2 n)!!    *)
```

How did I get this formula? Just invert this output:

```
u!! // FunctionExpand
(*    2^(u/2 + 1/4 (1 - Cos[π u])) π^(1/4 (-1 + Cos[π u])) Gamma[1 + u/2]    *)
```

### update

For a bit more automated judging of simplifications, we can define custom [transformation functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html) for [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html):

```
fac[z_] := z /. Gamma[t_] :> (t - 1)!
fac2[z_] := z /. Gamma[t_] :> FullSimplify[2^(1-t)*(π/2)^((1-Cos[2π(t-1)])/4)] (2(t-1))!!

Assuming[n >= 0 && Element[n, Integers],
  FullSimplify[int, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, fac, fac2}]]

(*    (2 π (-1 + 2 n)!!)/(2 n)!!    *)
```

Comment: A great answer. Especially, update solves the problem of converting `Gamma` to `Factorial`  (`Factorial2`). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
FullSimplify[(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + n])/
  Gamma[1 + n], {n \[Element] Integers, n > 0}]
  
(*  (2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[1/2 + n])/n!  *)
```

??

Comment: ?? There is still a `Gamma` function in your result.

Comment: Well, better than nothing.